# Filter out part of _layout on a specific template

Tags: templating, segments

I have a site consisting of 15 templates, all of which extend `_layout.html`.  There is just one page (homepage) which needs to omit a chunk of the `_layout.html`.  Is there something I can add to `_layout` which says "if I'm on the homepage leave this chunk of code out"?

Many thanks

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Sorry... while searching for an answer to something else I discovered the solution to this :/

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(1) != index.uri %}

    .... leave this chunk of code out

{% endif %}
```